# Remove undesirable fields from being returned in sails

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I am new to SailsJS and stuck in Data Model as follows:
I have a `User` model as follows:

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {
firstName: {
    type: 'string'
},
email: {
    type: 'email',
    required: true
},

password: {
    type: 'String'
},
passwordSalt: {
 type: 'String'
},
projects:{
 collection: 'ProjectMember',
 via: 'userId'
}  
}  
};
```

Task Model :

```
module.exports = {  
 taskName: {  
  type: 'String'  
 },  
 userId: {  
    model: 'User'  
 }
};
```

In Task model, it is getting all fields from User table which is not required while task data is rendered. I was planning to create one more model called `TinyUser` which stores only required fields to be shown when task data is rendered.

But `TinyUser` should just refer `User` table and get required data from it rather than we creating all data for TinyUser manually when user data is created.

Is there any way this can be achieved in Sails?
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question, but this will return a list of required attributes for any model

```
_.find(sails.models.<YOUR MODEL>._attributes, function(attr){return attr.required})
```

If your intent it to simply remove undesirable fields you can override the toJSON / toObject methods

see
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#toobjecttojson-instance-methods

Comment: I need to inherit User model and get some of attributes from it which includes both required and non-required attributes. But above code will just return me list of required attributes from User

Comment: I'm sorry, you question was "Getting required attributes from Sails Model"

Comment: `Required` in this context did not mean required keyword of Sails.. Sorry for confusion

Comment: I don't understand your question then, however all attributes are accessible on the sails global variable. You could use a variation of what I posted to match keys between two different models or use whatever criteria you need to filter attributes.

Comment: Right now, Since `Task` has a foreign key to `user`, When I try to fetch task data, along with task data it gets all user data like password, password-salt, addedOn, etc which is not required to be shown. I just need to show some of fields like firstName, lastName, email, projectMembers. So I planned to create a separate model called TinyUser which stores only necessary fields from User which have to be shown while task data is fetched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64249/discussion-between-abhishek-and-meeker).

Answer (score 0):

User.find({select:['firstName', 'email']}).exec()

Comment: When adding a new answer to an older question with an accepted answer, it might help everyone if you include why your suggestion is better. Has a newer version changed the chosen answer? Is there a specific reason that makes your answer more efficient? Just a suggestion for a new user.